# How to improve computational performances in GaussianProcessRegressor?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, gaussian-process

I need to fit my `GaussianProcessRegressor` with a lot of data. In particular, I start fitting the GP with few data, and I add more at each step. Since I need to simulate this for a lot of steps (and I must repeat the experiment hundreds of times), I am looking for a solution that is faster than calling the `.fit()` method for `n_steps*n_experiments` times.

I must use scikit-learn, and no other library.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: If I remember correctly you can pass a custom kernel function. Maybe using a compiled `jax`(https://github.com/google/jax) function you could speed up computations if your using the same kernel function over and over again.

Comment: https://github.com/ExpectationMax/sklearn-jax-kernels does exactly what I described above. So you only need to change a few imports.